# Is there an established name for this kind of function composition?

Tags: functions

$$
f : A → B
$$
$$
g : A×B → C
$$
$$
Cont(g, f)(x) = g(x, f(x))
$$
Is there an established name for $Cont$ operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$Cont(g,f)=g\circ (\rm Id_X\times f)$. So it is not just similar to function composition, it *is* function composition.

Comment: I edited the title a bit. Is there a more specific name than just "composition" that I can call the $Cont$ operation to emphasize that $g$ is binary and $f$ is unary, and that the second argument of $g$ is $f$ of first argument?

Comment: none that I know of.